# My Roblox Gui does not update while in game

Tags: gui, roblox

In my Roblox game, I'm trying to do 2 things with my UI: 1. I am trying to make the "Coins: " text = "Coins: " plus the number of coins the player has. 2. I am trying to make a shop Gui show up when you touch a part. But whenever it's updated, it doesn't show up in-game. I checked the properties while running the game and it says "Coins: 10" and "Enabled: True" but it doesn't show up in game, here are some images:

[image: It says "Coins: "]
[image: Properties shows "Coins: 10"]
[image: It says the Gui is enabled]
[image: Gui doesn't show up]

here is the coins script:

```
local part = script.Parent
local click = part.ClickDetector
local coinsGUI = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui2.TextLabel2
_G.damage = 1
local health = 10
local dealingDamage = false
_G.coins = 0
local coinsWorth = 10

local function onClick()
    while health > 0 do
        dealingDamage = true
        wait(1)
        health -= _G.damage
        print(health)
    end
    dealingDamage = false
    health = 0
    part.Transparency = 1
    part.CanCollide = false
    print("okay that works")
    _G.coins += coinsWorth
    print("that works too")
    coinsGUI.Text = "Coins: " .._G.coins
    print("okay")
    part.Transparency = 0
    print("i dont see what the problem is then")
    health = 10
    part.CanCollide = true
end

click.MouseClick:Connect(onClick)
```

and here is the shop script:

```
local part = script.Parent
local confirmGui = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui
local yesButton = confirmGui.TextButton2
local noButton = confirmGui.TextButton

print(confirmGui.Enabled)

--local function onTouch(coolPerson)
local function onTouch(coolPerson)
    print("function ran")
    local parent = coolPerson.Parent
    if game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(parent) then
        confirmGui.Enabled = true
        print("detects player")
    end
end

part.Touched:Connect(onTouch)
```

Comment: In future, please edit your existing question instead of deleting and re-posting about the same issue.

Comment: I did it because I also wanted to add another error and make it more general, but I could have edited it.

Comment: This could be a problem with client-sided vs. server-sided scripts. Can you tell us where you placed those scripts and whether they run client or server-sided?

Comment: I fixed it by using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=volfXKlW55c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the value in StarterGui, not the one in the player's GUI. StarterGUI is only used when a new player joins to give them the GUI.

Modify the GUI inside of `game.Players.[PlayerName].PlayerGUI`.

In your case, you should do the following:

Script 1:

```
[...]
game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(parent).PlayerGui.Enabled = true
[...]
```

Script 2:

```
[...]
local function onClick(plr)
    [...]
    plr.PlayerGui.ScreenGui2.TextLabel2.Text = "Coins: " .._G.coins
    [...]
end
[...]
```